# Append multiple rows at once with Google Sheets API

Tags: python, api, google-sheets, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to append multiple rows at once in a Google Sheets (via API from Google Cloud). Right now, my functions to connect and append are:

```
def connect_to_gsheet(data):
    # Create a connection object.
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
        data,
        scopes=[SCOPE],
    )
    service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=credentials)
    gsheet_connector = service.spreadsheets()
    return gsheet_connector

def add_row_to_gsheet(gsheet_connector, sheet_name, row) -> None:
    values = (
        gsheet_connector.values()
        .append(
            spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
            range=f"{sheet_name}!A:AO",
            body=dict(values=row),
            valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED",
        )
        .execute()
    )

with open('g_sheets_api.json', 'r') as f:
    json_file = json.load(f)
    gsheet_connector = connect_to_gsheet(json_file)
    sheet_name = "Bucket"
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
         add_row_to_gsheet(gsheet_connector, sheet_name, [[row[coluna] for coluna in lista_colunas]])
```

And it works. But as long as i'm in a free tier, i can only send 60 requests per minute. So, for a dataframe with 600 lines, i would have to spend 10 minutes (1 line per second). I was wondering if is there a way to append a whole dataframe. I have tried something like...

```
add_row_to_gsheet(gsheet_connector, sheet_name, df.to_json())
```

But unfortunately, it dont work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate) API, which will allow you to append multiple rows and/or columns in a single request. I'm not a Python developer so I don't know the correct syntax, but based on the example that's in the linked page, it might be like this (this is an educated guess based on my experience in C#):

```
batch_update_values_request_body = {
    'value_input_option': 'USER_ENTERED',
    'data': [{
        'range': 'A1:C3', # this defines the area you are editing
        'values': [
            [ 'A1', 'B1', 'C1' ],
            [ 'A2', 'B2', 'C2' ],
            [ 'A3', 'B3', 'C3' ]
        ],
        'major_dimension': 'ROWS' # this means the data values represent rows
    }, {
        # repeat as necessary
    }],
    'include_values_in_response': true
}
```